# Passed JSON collection not picked up by controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, binding

I have the following javascript snippet:

```
$.ajax({
            url: self.LoadCirculationListUrl,
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: [ { "ColumnName":"France","Comparitor":"=","Value":"1"},{"ColumnName":"Germany","Comparitor":">","Value":"3"}] 
        });
```

Here is the controllre which is accessed from the above ajax call:

```
public ActionResult LoadCirculationData(IList<CirculationListFilter> filters)
{
}
```

Here is the `CirculationListFilter` class

```
public sealed class CirculationListFilter
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }

    public string Comparitor { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I run the code, the controller does not get the JSON collection passed to it; `filters` is always null. However, if I do this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: self.LoadCirculationListUrl,
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { "ColumnName":"Germany","Comparitor":">","Value":"3"}
        });
```

and the contoller is like this:

```
public ActionResult LoadCirculationData(CirculationListFilter filters)
{
}
```

The data is passed fine. Why can't the controller bind a collection of JSON items?

EDIT:

I changed the AJAX call to use this:

```
data: { filters: [{ "ColumnName": "France", "Comparitor": "=", "Value": "1" }, { "ColumnName": "Germany", "Comparitor": ">", "Value": "3" }]},
```

and the ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult LoadCirculationData(List<CirculationListFilter> filters)
```

Now `filters` has 2 items inside of it, but each of the `CirculationListFilter` classes are populated with NULL data in their properties. So I'm getting closer, but the actual values are not being binded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the .ajax() call.

.ajax() doesn't convert the data into JSON string.

The reason why it works for one item is because .ajax() was able to convert the data into a query string which MVC happily accepted.

The solution is to convert the JSON into string first:

```
$.ajax({
            url: self.LoadCirculationListUrl,
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify([ { "ColumnName":"France","Comparitor":"=","Value":"1"},{"ColumnName":"Germany","Comparitor":">","Value":"3"}]) 
        });
```

Comment: Looking at your code, I do believe it should work, but when I try it, the collection of items is always empty. I will have to bite the bullet and use my not-so-ideal JavaScriptSerializer approach. I will come back to this later....

Comment: That is odd.. I verified my solution before posting (and re-verified just now). I'm using ASP MVC3 and JQuery 1.5.1. Hope this helps

Comment: Not sure if it's something really subtle going on here. As I said, your code does look correct to the naked eye. :(

Comment: OK I'm trying this out at home with a bare-bones MVC project. I still can't get this to work. @EugeneO can you also show your controller code please?

Comment: Found my problem. I added `type : 'POST'` to the `$.ajax()` call and now the JSON binder has kicked in. I now have a collection of items pre-binded for me in the controller. (FYI: Declaring the items as `IList<>` does work). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found another solution:

Ajax call:

```
data: { 'json': '[{ "ColumnName": "France", "Comparitor": "=", "Value": "1" }, { "ColumnName": "Germany", "Comparitor": ">", "Value": "3" }]' },
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult LoadCirculationData(string json)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    var obj = js.Deserialize<List<CirculationListFilter>>(json);
}
```

The above gives me the items that I need. Really not sure why the JSON binder doesn't do this by default.

Comment: That is just inefficient, I'd say; see @EugeneO's answer for the correct approach that uses MVC data-binding.

Comment: @subkamran Do you mind not down-voting my answer please? I've just looked at the code for `JsonValueProviderFactory` (which is MVC's JSON model binder for JSON data) and the method `GetDeserializedObject()` actually uses `JavaScriptSerializer` itself. So although my answer is not ideal, it's not less efficient than the default model binder, since it uses the same code. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recieve in this format

```
public ActionResult LoadCirculationData(IList<CirculationListFilter> filters)
{
}
```

You need to post it in next format data: {

```
{
"ColumnName[0]":"Germany","Comparitor[0]":">","Value[0]":"3",
"ColumnName[1]":"Germany","Comparitor[1]":">","Value[1]":"3",
"ColumnName[2]":"Germany","Comparitor[2]":">","Value[2]":"3",
"ColumnName[3]":"Germany","Comparitor[3]":">","Value[3]":"3",
"ColumnName[4]":"Germany","Comparitor[4]":">","Value[4]":"3",
}
```